# Uncaught TypeError: e.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've got error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle is not a function
at HTMLSpanElement.e.addEventListener
```

The weird thing is when I change: `el.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle()` to: `el.nextElementSibling.remove()` - everything works fine. Any ideas?

```
$(function () {

    const spans = $('span');
    const lists = $('ul')
    const newArr = [];

    for (x of spans) {
        newArr.push(x);
    }

    newArr.forEach(fn)

    function fn(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => el.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle();
        )
    }

})
```

Comment: The error message you've provided is different than the code you're showing. Are you sure the issue is not coming from somewhere else? `e.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle` is not `el.nextElementSibling.fadeToggle`

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I've got only this code. It's small exercise. Only two documents -> app.js and index.html. That's it.

Comment: You're doing a whole bunch of things that, because you're using jQuery, are entirely unnecessary. Just select all spans and call `.click` directly on that query list.

Comment: adeneo is likely right, your issue comes from mixing javascript & jquery. Javascript cannot use jquery objects/methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you do this? jQuery was designed specifically to do things in a nice and concise manner without unpacking/repacking:

```
$(() => {
  const fade = function() {
    let el = this.nextSibling;
    if (el) $(el).toggleFade();
  };

  $('span').click(fade);
});
```

And we're done.

You can use almost any jQuery function on the result of a jQuery selection. Just make sure that you are ***absolutey not*** using an arrow function, because arrow functions are explicitly meant to preserve what `this` means based on the scope it's declared in, which is the opposite of what you want to have happen when you're using jQuery.

Comment: Ooh.. Thank you, now i see where i made a mistake. That's true i mixed js and jQuery. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`fadeToogle` is likely a jQuery method, while `nextElementSibling` is a regular DOM element.

You'd have to wrap it up in jQuery to use jQuery methods, as in

```
$(el.nextElementSibling).fadeToggle()
```

The real question is why are you doing this at all, when you could do

```
$(function() {
    $('span').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next().fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

The reason `remove()` works, is because there's both a jQuery version and a native version that works the same way, so with a regular DOM element you're calling the native `remove()`, not jQuery's version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `.remove` works is that because it's built-in in the [ChildNode API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). However, `fadeToggle()` is jQuery-only. You have to "jquerize" your element to make your code work (include it in `$(...)`). Like this:

```js
// toggle the next sibling every 2s
setInterval(() => {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    $(this.nextElementSibling).fadeToggle();
  });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>some</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
<div>
  the <code>nextElementSibling</code> of the list
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! But keep in mind that, eventhough it feels weird for new Stack Overflow users, *thank-you comments* should be avoided. Instead, upvote and/or accept answers that respond best to your question. - from [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)